# Limits of functions with the property $f(x) \geqslant g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be two functions such that the property $f(x) \geqslant g(x)$ holds for all $x \in A.$
>
> Show that if both $f$ and $g$ have a limit at $x_0$, then $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) \geqslant \lim_{x\to x_0} g(x).$$

My plan was to use contradiction by making the assumption that $\exists x_o$ for which $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=b$ such that $b>a$, but I didn't manage to get this to work. Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Take $\epsilon =\frac {b-a} 2$ in the definition of limit and try to get a contradiction.

Comment: Keep going. Consider what happens when both functions come within $\varepsilon = \frac{b - a}{2}$ of their limits, i.e. half the distance between them. Surely then $g(x) < f(x)$?

Comment: I see that this would work, but how does one come up with $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Daniel I think about it in terms of the graphs. The functions have to become close to their limits. If the limit of $f$ is below the limit of $g$, then at some point, the graphs have to switch the inequality. Taking $\varepsilon$ to be half the distance between the limits achieves this, as it means that $f$ and $g$ have to occupy disjoint intervals, with $f$ below $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ defined on $D:A \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $$f(x) \geqslant g(x)  \forall x \in D$$.
Then $lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) \geqslant lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} g(x) $

Proof:

$$lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) =L$$ and  $$lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} g(x) =M$$

Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)   \forall x \in D$

Then we have:

(1) $h(x) \geqslant 0  \forall x \in D$

(2)$lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} h(x) $ exists and
 $lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} h(x) =L-M$  (by theorem)

(3) $lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} h(x) \geqslant 0$ (by theorem)

Now from (2) and (3) we have:

$L-M \geqslant 0 $

i.e. $L \geqslant M$

Therefore  $lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) \geqslant lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} g(x) _{\blacksquare}$

Comment: This was a nice approach!

Comment: Glad to heard that. You need Real Analysis' Books in 1 variable.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the limits, you will find two respective neighborhoods of $a$ and $b$ that only contain values of $f$ and $g$,

$$|f(x)-a|, |g(x)-b|<\epsilon<|b-a|.$$

But if $a<b$, that contradicts $f(x)\ge g(x)$.